# Поведение recycleview при появлении snackbar

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, coordinator-layout

Пытаюсь нормализовать смещение recycleview при появлении snackbar.
recycleview находится во фрагменте который заменяет framelayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.rodgersdevelop.listsformagazine.ActivityMain"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Если ничего не делать последний элемент списка будет скрыт наполовину.
Если добавляю параметр
app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom" 
Нааборот скрывает самый верхний элемент.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?